# Input App showing only two pictures

Tags: qgis, input

[image]I am trying to add more than one pic in my QGIS project layer. Like in any one feature layer add new field (pic1, pic2,pic3, pic4 etc), but problem is Input App shows only two images in mobile Input App. and for 3 image I found image not available.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am using Input App for my QGIS project. After load the QGIS project(geopackage) everything is fine and when I take images for specific feature layer with fields (pic1, pic2, pic3, pic 4..) with mobile directly then Input App in mobile shows for 3rd pic that image not available but fine with 2 images. I mean I face the problem with more than 2 images

Comment: I found the missed thing, I have to mark here. See the pink circle.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to have multiple pictures is to use 1-to-many relations. In QGIS you can link two tables with a unique key:
1- The geometry table contains one field
2- A none-spatial table containing the a field to be linked with the geometry table.

Then you can use 1-to-many relations to link the two tables. Once the tables are linked, you can set the widget accordingly (as you have done) within the non-spatial table. This will allow you to have multiple photos linked to your geometry table. Input app displays the photos in a custom gallery.

[image]

For further reading:
Manual page to set up multiple photos: https://merginmaps.com/docs/howto/project/settingup_forms/#link-multiple-photos-to-a-single-feature

An example project with such settings: https://public.cloudmergin.com/projects/documentation/forms_multiple_photos

Comment: Great answer from the developers !